# Given $f \in \text{GL}(V)$ and $f^3 + f^2 + f = 0$ find the minimal polynomial of $f$.

Tags: linear-algebra, minimal-polynomials

> Let $V$ be a real normed vector space, $A \in \text{GL}(V)$ a bijective linear function from $V$ to $V$ that fulfils
>   $$ \tag{$\star$}
> A^3 + A^2 + A = 0.
> $$
>   Find the minimal polynomial of $A$.

**My ideas**
Since $A$ is invertible, ($\star$) is equivalent to
$$ \tag{$\ddagger$}
A^2 + A + E = 0,
$$
implying that $E = - A^2 - A$.
Adding both equations gives
$$
A^3 + A^2 + A - A^2 - A = E
\implies A^3 = E.
$$
Again, because $A$ is invertible, we can also deduce $A^2 = A^{-1}$.

Therefore, I expect $A$ to be "periodic" in the sense that there exists a $n$ (maybe $n = 2$?) such that $A^k = A^{k + n}$ for all $k \in \mathbb{N}$.

Another idea I had was substituting the results back into ($\star$) to obtain
$$
E + A^{-1} + A = 0
$$
Multiplication with $A$ yields
$$
A + E + A^2 = 0,
$$
but subtracting both equations only yields the familiar $A^2 = A^{-1}$.

How may I proceed?

**Edit 1:**
The preceding task asked for the following:

Let $f: V \to V$ be linear such that $f^2 + f$ has the eigenvalue $1$. Show that $f^3$ has the eigenvalue $-1$.

When solving this I found that this $f$ satisfies ($\star$).
Could one build an answer to the above question from that?

**Edit 2:**
I also know that $m_A(t) := t^2 + t + 1$ could be the minimal polynomial, since $m_{A}(A) = 0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint** Since $A^2+A+E=0$ the minimal polynomial divides $x^2+x+1$ and hence it is one of the following

- $x^2+x+1$
- $x-\omega$
- $x-\bar{\omega}$

Where $\omega =\frac{-1+i\sqrt{3}}{2}$.

Note that the last two situations imply that $A = \pm \omega E$.

If your vector space is complex there is nothing more you can say. If your vector space is over $\mathbb R$ (or if the matrix is real) you can deduce that the last two are not possible, since $A \notin M_n(\mathbb R)$.

If you work over an arbitrary field $k$, all three or only the first are possible depending if $x^2+x+1$ has root in $k$ or not.

Comment: I forgot to mention that $V$ is real. Where do you get $\omega$ from? I thought that $$x^2 + x + 1  = (x + (-1)^{\frac{1}{3}})(x - (-1)^{\frac{2}{3}})$$

Comment: @ViktorGlombik $\omega=-(-1)^\frac{1}{3}$ and $\bar{\omega}= (-1)^\frac{2}{3}$ (or the other way around depending on which branch you chose)....

Comment: @ViktorGlombik But you are overkilling it by looking at $(-1)^\frac{*}{3}$....It is much easier to solve the quadratic equation $$x^2+x+1=0$$ The roors are $$x_{1,2}=\frac{-1 \pm \sqrt{1-4}}{2}$$